# Single field output with Views

Tags: views, 7

I am having a view of users, in that I have added a field "Status" which is from the core Drupal 7 to display the user which are "Active" or "Blocked".

What I am trying to achieve is that:

1. <strike>I should get a clickable link to the field value status, assuming if its "active"</strike> **Achived**, here I have just rewritted the output

   ```
   "user/[uid]/edit?destination=admin/people"
   ```

   checked with

   ```
   Use absolute path
   ```

   itself in the View.
2. When I click on it I should only get a page with only value of "Status" where I can change the status of the clicked user; here I am stuck, any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module? This allows you to perform operations on entities from your actual View page.

I've never used it with Users before, but I've managed to use it to Publish / Unpublish nodes from my own custom View's page.

Comment: Its totally a different thing AlexK, what I need is "When I click on it I should only get a page with only value of "Status" where I can change the status of the clicked user"